# replace ng-form with angular 5 form in hybrid application

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have an AngularJS application with HTML as below.

```
<form name="completeForm">
  <first-step></first-step>
  <second-step></second-step>
  <third-step></third-step>
  <fourth-step></fourth-step>
  <fifth-step></fifth-step>
</form>
```

Form will continue to next step after validating the current step by a button click event.

Each step directive HTML is implemented through `ng-form` tag as below.

```
<first-step></first-step> => <ng-form name="firstForm"></ng-form>
<second-step></second-step> => <ng-form name="secondForm"></ng-form>
<third-step></third-step> => <ng-form name="thirdForm"></ng-form>
<fourth-step></fourth-step> => <ng-form name="fourthForm"></ng-form>
<fifth-step></fifth-step> => <ng-form name="fifthForm"></ng-form>
```

I want to replace one of the steps (second-step) with an implementation using Angular 5, thus making it a hybrid application.

I should be able to replace the second-step in Angular 5. The HTML related to it is as below.

```
<form  #secondForm="ngForm">
.....
  <input type="text"  #email="ngModel" name="email"  [(ngModel)]="$scope.email" required />
  <span *ngIf="!email.valid">please enter the input</span> 
...
</form>
```

But the validation I have implemented on this Angular 5 step is not working. It is moving to the next step without validating on the 
button click event. Form is always found to be valid.
Form Controller is not recognizing the secondForm defined as 
`<form  #secondForm="ngForm">`.

I tried to replace the form tag (as form at the parent level cannot have another form within it) with div tag as below but no impact at all.

```
<div ngForm #secondForm="ngForm">
```

Please could anyone help.